# How to select a part of a string OR another with REGEXP in MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab

I've been trying to solve this problem in the last few days with no success. I have the following string:

```
   comment = '#disabled, Fc = 200Hz'
```

What I need to do is: if there's the string `'disabled'` it needs to be matched. Otherwise I need to match the number that comes before `'Hz'`.

The closest solution I found so far was:

```
  regexpi(comment,'\<#disabled\>|\w*Hz\>','match') ;
```

It will match the word `'#disabled'` or anything that comes before `'Hz'`. Problem is that when it first finds `'#disabled#'` it copies also the result `'200Hz'`.

So I'm getting:

```
ans = '#disabled' '200Hz'
```

Summing up, I need to select only the `'disabled'` part of a string if there is one, otherwise I need to get the number before `'Hz'`.

Can someone give me a hand ?

Comment: you are limited to one line...?

Comment: No, actually I'm not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose your input is:

```
comment = {'#disabled, Fc = 200Hz';
                      'Fc = 300Hz'}
```

The regular expression (match disabled if follows `#` otherwise match digits if they are followed by `Hz`):

```
regexp(comment, '(?<=^#)disabled|\d+(?=Hz)','match','once')
```

Explaining it:

- `^#` - match `#` at the beginning of the line
- `(?<=expr)disabled` - match `disabled` **if** follows `expr`
- `expr1 | expr2` - otherwise match `expr2`
- `\d+` - match 1 or more digits, equivalently `[0-9]+`
- `expr(?=Hz)` - match `expr` only if followed by `'Hz'`

Diagram:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/eKuaFX3_iewMrXvd)

Comment: Could you explain the matching expression ?